# Vim: tab-align multiple lines?

Tags: linux, vim

In GUI style editors, you can generally select multiple lines, press tab a few times to move all the lines across (or shift-tab to go back). I have no idea how to do this in VIM.

I googled around and couldn't find any straight answer to I came here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use >> to indent, << to unindent.  So you could go to the first line and press 5>> to indent the following five lines.  Or use V and select lines in visual mode, then > to indent them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [some useful information about using vim](http://vim.wikia.com/index.php?title=Indenting_source_code&oldid=26488), too.